# Using Java applet methods in HTML

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet, awt

I have an applet which has 2 methods that I want to use. On the first method, I am getting client printer list.

I want to use this printer list on my HTML page in a combo. The user is expected to choose a printer from this combo. After that, the user will click a button to do some operations. After clicking that button and finishing those operations, I want to call
the second method of my applet, which gets two parameters, one is a file object, other is a printer object that user already selected.

**My questions are:**

How can I get printer list and use it on my HTML page after page loads?
How can I send parameters to second method of my applet after clicking the button?

Comment: My advice would be to sort this in an application first (with no default security sand-box) before trying it in an applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
To have my applet work;
1- I exported the applet as jar file(named as printApplet.jar) and copied it under the same folder as my xhtml page.
2- I put the applet in xhtml as below;
         <applet id="myApplet"
            code="com.xxx.yyy.console.action.PrintApplet"
            archive="printApplet.jar" width="1" height="1">         
        </applet>
3- I created a method `enter code here`in the applet which gets printer names as string and has comma(,) between the names. 
4- I called the applet methods using javascript as below;
<script type="text/javascript" >
    //<![CDATA[
    function getPrinters() {
        var aplt = document.getElementById("myApplet");     
        var printers = aplt.getPrinterNames();
        var p = printers.split(',');
        var c = document.getElementById("combo");
        for ( var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            var o = document.createElement("option");
            o.text = p[i];
            o.value = i;
            try {
                c.add(o, null); //Standard 
            } catch (error) {
                c.add(o); // IE only
            }
        }
    }   
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use object id tag in the html/jsp

```
<object id="appletId" type="application/x-java-applet"
```

and to get the list of printers you should call the applet method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPrinters(){
    return appletId.getPrinters();
}
</script>
```

assumed the applet has the public method `getPrinters` that return an array of strings.

Comment: Thanks, this was close but not exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use browser combo box. Use [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) or [Choice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Choice.html) directly in the applet so you can do everything without going out. It is possible as described by @Roman C but seems too complex for the task you describe.